# Rows not showing in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, arcgis-10.5

I have a problem with a shapefile I created exporting features from another shapefile.

I have all my lines visible but their rows only appear in the attribute table window when they're selected, do you know why and how can I fix this ? (I posted pictures to illustrate my problem)

selected lines

[image]

unselected lines

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

You have hit the button that only shows selected items in the attribute table. If you click the button next to it you can see them all.

Comment: I think this is a good question - I've seen it stump a lot of occasional arcmap users.

Comment: @tony-bof Don't feel too bad. ArcGIS has a truly awful UX. I often have trouble finding that button when I actually want to enable it, in spite of knowing it exists.